# can't connect line between points in pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

this is the code:

```
 def make_ax(fdist,N):

        ys= list(fdist.values())

        for i in range(len(ys)):
            ys[i] = (ys[i]/N)

        d = (list(fdist.values()))
        c= list(reversed(sorted(list(set(d)))))
        xs =[]
        for i in range(len(d)):

            xs.append((c.index(d[i])+1))

        return xs,ys


 def plot_graph(words):
    fdist = FreqDist(words)
    axis_x,axis_y= make_ax(fdist,len(words))
    plt.figure()
    plt.xlabel('log rank')
    plt.ylabel('log Probability')
    plt.plot(axis_x,axis_y,'ko')
```

Now, xs and ys with the same length, and they are list.
But for some reason, i keep getting this:

How to connect a line between the dots?
[image]

**UPDATE:**
if i write `plt.plot(axis_x,axis_y,'ko-')` it gives me this:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `plt.plot(axis_x,axis_y,'k-')` instead?

Comment: @JoséSánchez yes, didn't help. see update

Comment: As you can see from the answers and comments you get, people are definitely trying to help you, but you are not really helping them by not providing a [MCVE] that reproduces the issue and by not mentionning where `words` come from and what `FreqDist` is. Therefore people are in the dark and just have to guess about what could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `plt.plot(axis_x,axis_y,'ko')` by `plt.plot(axis_x,axis_y,'ko-')`.
The `-` tells pyplot to draw lines between the dots.

See `plt.plot` documentation for more details on the options (line style, marker style, ...).

**EDIT**

I modified `make_ax` to sort the points:

```
def make_ax(fdist,N):

    ys= list(fdist.values())

    for i in range(len(ys)):
        ys[i] = (ys[i]/N)

    d = (list(fdist.values()))
    c= list(reversed(sorted(list(set(d)))))
    xs =[]
    for i in range(len(d)):

        xs.append((c.index(d[i])+1))
    # make a list of tuples of coordinates
    points = list(zip(xs, ys)) 
    # sort point according to their x coordinate
    points.sort(key=lambda point: point[0])
    axis_x, axis_y = [], []
    for x, y in points:
        axis_x.append(x)
        axis_y.append(y)
    return axis_x, axis_y
```

and now, the lines should be between the right points.

Comment: @user3552460 I suppose that axis_x is not sorted, so your (x,y) points are not drawn in the order of increasing x values, hence the zigzagging lines

Comment: Can you give us the first few points of `axis_x` and `axis_y`?  I really don't see why it does not work.

Comment: I guess the idea is not to sort the points at all, but only the `y` values in reversed order. The initial code from the question was very misleading in the sense that it also tried to sort `x` in some way, which seems to be unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `nltk` here, and its `FreqDist` method returns an unsorted list.
Therefore you need to sort that list in reversed order. However you do not need to sort the `x` values in any way.

It may make sense to use numpy for that purpose, but that is no requirement.
For plotting use `linestyle="-"` to obtain a line.

The following plots the probability distribution of the 80 most frequent words in *Moby Dick by Herman Melville*:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from nltk import FreqDist
from nltk.book import text1

def make_ax(fdist,N):
        # normalize frequency values
        ys = np.array(fdist.values()) / float(N)
        # sort frequency values, then invert list, such that most frequent words come first
        ys = np.sort(ys)[::-1]
        #create an x range
        xs = np.arange(len(ys))+1.
        return xs,ys


def plot_graph(words):
    fdist = FreqDist(words)
    axis_x,axis_y= make_ax(fdist,len(words))

    plt.figure()
    plt.xlabel('rank') # no log here in this example
    plt.ylabel('Probability')
    plt.plot(axis_x[:80],axis_y[:80], #only plot the 80 most frequent words
             color="k", marker="o", markersize="2", linestyle="-", linewidth=0.8)
    # equall possible:
    # plt.plot(axis_x[:80],axis_y[:80], "ko-")

plot_graph(text1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `plt.plot(axis_x, axis_y, marker='o', color='k'  linestyle='solid')` or alternatively: `plt.plot(axis_x, axis_y, marker='o', color='k'  linestyle='-')`

That is way longer to write, but increases the readability of your code as well. Specifing the keywords is a good practice in python as well.

Documentation of `plt.plot()`: [Matplotlib.pyplot.plot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot)